# NSTimer in a for loop

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I want to call the getData method after waiting 2 seconds each time this loop...loops.  I've written out the NSTimer a number of times inside and outside the loop but can't get the correct usage for it to do what I want.

```
for (TwitterPerson *person in [tempDict allValues]) {

        [self getDataFromTwitterUserAPIandArchiveFor:person.handle];

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you set it up differently and call the `[getData...` method every time the timer fires? You could keep your dictionary keys in an array and pop the next key each time the timer fired.

I think the NSTimer is designed to not block the main thread whereas the `for-loop` definitely blocks the thread.

As in this related question [Using NSTimer in a Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4590524/962009), you might consider NSRunLoop.