# How would you sense a held button?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, button, timer, uibutton

How would I code something to sense if a certain button is being held down? and how would I add a timer into my application?

Regards, Nikita.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILongPressGestureRecognizer). With it you can configure a minimumPressDuration, which may fulfill your need for a timer, and if it does not then [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) is pretty easy to work with.

Comment: Thanks, one more question, How would I make an NSTimer call a method every second

Comment: There are a few ways, such as having your NSTimer call inside your method such that every time it runs it queues up the next call, like in the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590524/using-nstimer-in-a-loop